# Send IP datagram (not UDP)

Tags: protocols, datagram

is there a way to create an IP datagram (preferably in Java)? I am not talking about UDP, but just the raw IP header and eventually some data. I don't care if the receiver can't understand this message, i just want to know if this is possible.

If not - why not? Of course i tried to google, but the results are always about UDP.

Thank you!

**Edit:**

**Ok, the buzzword for my problem is "raw sockets" and there seems to be a library for java, too:
http://www.savarese.com/software/rocksaw/**

Comment: `libpcap` might help, AFAIK it is portable.

Comment: this looks promising. i will give it a try. Thank you!